# External Filters in R Shiny Application

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following table (left many of the combinations out for brevity):

```
Name      r2     pvalue    t-statistic
a1
b1
c1
a1 & b1
a1 & c1
b1& c1
a1 & b1 & c1
....
```

Where a1, b1, and c1, were created from the vectors

```
a = c("a1", "a2")
b = c("b1","b2","b3")
c = c("c1")
```

I want to create a Shiny table exactly like the one in the link https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/basic-datatable.html except for one issue. In that example the filters are actually columns in the table whereas I want to be able to choose "a1" and "c1" and get only the ones with a1 and c1. I essentially want to be able to use the vectors shown to find strings in the name column that contain the values I select. Does anyone know how to do this? All the examples I have found use filters that are already columns in the table.

Comment: What do you want your filters to be? How many filters do you want? What does "name column" in this sentence mean 'I essentially want to be able to use the vectors shown to find strings in the name column that contain the values I select.'

Comment: Name column is the first column in the table. To make things clearer as you can see each vector a,b, c contains elements. I want each of these vectors to be a filter and the values in the vector are the options for each filter. So for example if I select a1 and c1 I want to be shown only rows that have a1 & c1. Additionally the number of filters is going to be dependent on the number of columns I have in an external table.

Comment: So in this example the external table is a list of lists that holds a,b,c vectors. I want to iterate through this list and dynamically create three filters a, b,c with the values in the vectors as inputs for each filter.

Comment: Understood so far. What I don't understand is when you say "I want to be shown only rows that have a1 & c1", what exactly does that mean? "a1" and "c1" in which column of the row?

Comment: Oh apologies the Name column

Comment: So in the above example if I clicked a1 on the a filter and c1 on the c filter I would be shown rows 5 and 7.

Comment: Also some of the row names have parentheses like abs(a1) so I've been running into issues using %like% because it breaks when parentheses are in the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution based on your example data. You can change the filtering conditions by changing the logic inside filter() function.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

a = c("a1", "a2")
b = c("b1","b2","b3")
c = c("c1")

# Create dummy data
Name <- c("a1", "b1", "c1", "a1 & b1", "a1 & c1", "b1& c1", "a1 & b1 & c1")
# Random numbers
r2 <- runif(length(Name))
p.value <- runif(length(Name))
t.statistic <- runif(length(Name))

dummy.df <- cbind.data.frame(Name, r2, pvalue, t.statistic)

# Define UI
#ui <- fluidPage(
 # sidebarPanel(
  #  selectInput("a.list", "Select As", a),
   # selectInput("b.list", "Select Bs", b),
   # selectInput("c.list", "Select Cs", c)
  #),
  #mainPanel(
   # tableOutput("tab1"),
    #tableOutput("tab2")
  #)

    # Create a new Row in the UI for selectInputs
  fluidRow(
    column(4, selectInput("a.list", "Select As", a)
    ),
    column(4, selectInput("b.list", "Select Bs", b)
    ),
    column(4, selectInput("c.list", "Select Cs", c)
    )
  ),
  # Create a new row for the table.
  fluidRow(
    column(8, tableOutput("tab2"))
  )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output){
  # Table with all the data
  output$tab1 <- renderTable(dummy.df)

  # Apply filter to data
  foo <- reactive({
    dummy.df %>%
    filter(Name %like% input$a.list & Name %like% input$c.list)
  })

  # Table with filtered data - returns rows 5 and 7
  output$tab2 <- renderTable(foo())
}

# Create shiny app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is very close to what I'm looking for! I just had a couple of questions as a follow up. How would l make the filters look like the example where they are at the top of the graph? Is there a generic way to do it with a loop because in this example there are vectors a,b,c but in my actual code I am going to loop through the columns of a separate matrix to get each vector so there might be more or less than 3. Also in this example the second table is below the first- is there any way to make it a separate tab?

Comment: Edited for displaying filters like the example. You can replace a,b,c by something like `a = MAT[, "col.name.for.A"]` etc where `MAT` is your separate matrix to extract columns. See https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/tabPanel.html to read more about how you can create tabs in a shiny app.

Comment: So how would I make the filter generic so its not hard coded like in foo()?

Comment: For example how would I include just filtering by a, or a and b, or a b and c, or if I had more vectors?

Comment: So the number of filters in your app will be variable, depending upon the number of column in the separate matrix, right?

Comment: That would be a little tricky to figure out. I suggest you ask it as a separate question.